# Entity Framework Code First - Delete migrations table?

Tags: entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-migrations

before EF Migrations (V 4.1), I could "cheat" quite easy on my dev machine if I wanted to create e.g. a new property / column for an entity:

I would create that column in the database and I would add that property to my entity - it worked and I didn't have to recreate my database.

The same "cheat" doesn't work anymore with V4.3. Can I still somehow do this with V 4.3, e.g. delete the migrations table or do some other tricks - strictly for a quick dev process?

Thx
Eau

Comment: But what's wrong with migrations doing the work for you?

Comment: Well, nothing of course, I just wanted to know if there's an easier and quicker way to try something out

Comment: Or, perhaps, it doesn't work. I have changed the ENTIRE INHERITANCE HEIRARCHY of my Code First project, and I keep getting `No pending code-based migrations.`

Comment: I'm wondering about the same thing. Would love to see an answer on this.